# Creating a password protected postgresql dump file in java

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, zip

I am creating a PostgreSQL database backup which is executing fine but I want to protect the dump file with password within the Java file within a password to prevent an authorized access.

How can I zip the dump file in java and protect the file with password?

Comment: Seems to have nothing to do with PostgreSQL. You want to create an *encrypted zip file* from Java, right, using symmetric encryption with a password?

Comment: @Craig Ringer I want the postgresql dumpfile to be zipped with a password